# One incorrect SSH login attempt locks me out for an hour

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I've never observed this problem neither did any of my colleagues trying to SSH into the same system. If I try logging into my server using a wrong username and then press ^C to terminate or exhaust my password attempts, I am locked out for at least an hour. Is there something I can do on my end to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use a wrong password (or use public key authentification in the first place) ;)

Your admins might run something like fail2ban, blockhosts or similar on your IP range but not on your colleagues' -- but this is only my guess. If you really want to find out why this happens only to you you should contact your site admins, since they know their setup (as opposed to us).

Comment: Thanks... I was thinking the problem was on my end. I will contact them.